# Como adicionar a Toolbar na Activity sem herdar AppCompatActivity - Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, herança

Boa noite.

Atualizei meu `Android Studio` para versão 1.4 e por default, qualquer `activity` criada utiliza como herança a `AppCompatActivity` `(public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity)`. Desenvolvi um app que necessita herdar uma classe responsável por controlar o ciclo de vida de cada `activity` como no exemplo a seguir: `public class MainActivity extends LifeCycleActivity`. O problema é que ao fazer isso, o nome do projeto não aparece na `toolbar` ao executar o app. Como a atualização do `Android Studio`trouxe dois layouts (`content_main.xml` e `activity_main.xml`) para cada `activity`, gostaria de saber se resolvo o problema da exibição do nome do projeto na `toolbar` através dos próprios arquivos de layout, ou através de código, uma vez que não estou utilizando como herança a `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Faça `LifeCycleActivity` herdar de `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Segui a ajuda que recebi e a solução foi resolvida fazendo a classe `LifeCycleActivity` herdar de `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Quando criamos ActionBar sem AppCompatActivity voce precisa de definir o layout do ActionBar no seu xml. Coloque o código abaixo como primeiro elemento do seu layout.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    />
```

De seguida coloque na respectiva Activity (no método onCreate) o seguinte:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTittle("titulo");
```

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score -1):

É só configurar o title da toobar.

```
Toolbar toobar  = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toobar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("seu título");
```

Comment: O problema é que sem o extend na AppCompatActivity, o código retorna erro no 'setSupportActionBar(toolbar);'.

Comment: Não seria `setActionBar(toolbar);`